# Joining to MAX date record in group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Job
--------
Id
Description


JobStatus
----------
Id
JobId
StatusTypeId
Date
```

How do I get the current `JobStatus` for all jobs?

so something like....

```
SELECT * FROM Job j
INNER JOIN ( /* Select rows with MAX(Date) grouped by JobId */ ) s
    ON j.Id = s.JobId
```

(I'm sure there are a bunch of similar questions already but I couldn't find anything which exactly does what I need).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL Subquery Max(Date) and Joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879111/t-sql-subquery-maxdate-and-joins)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In `SQL Server 2005+`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    job j
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    jobstatus js
        WHERE   js.jobid = j.jobid
        ORDER BY
                js.date DESC
        ) js
```

In `SQL Server 2000`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    job j
LEFT JOIN
        jobstatus js
ON      js.id =
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 id
        FROM    jobstatus jsi
        WHERE   jsi.jobid = j.jobid
        ORDER BY
                jsi.date DESC
        )
```

These queries handle possible duplicates on `Date` correctly.

Comment: How have I been missing this since 2005! Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Just blew my mind... Is this standard SQL or specific to SQL Server?

Comment: @openwonk: _TOP_ is specific to SQL Server, most other SQL dialects use _LIMIT_

Comment: @Quassnoi, I was referring to `OUTER APPLY`

Comment: @openwonk: oh sorry, yes, this is called `LATERAL` in the SQL standard. PostgreSQL and Oracle do support it.

Answer (score 10):

One way is this:

```
SELECT j.*, s2.StatusTypeId, s2.Date
FROM Job j
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT JobId, MAX(Date) AS LatestStatusDate
        FROM JobStatus 
        GROUP BY JobId
    ) s1 ON j.JobId = s1.JobId
    JOIN JobStatus s2 ON s1.JobId = s2.JobId AND s1.LatestStatusDate = s2.Date
```

Assuming you won't have 2 rows in JobStatus for the same JobId + Date combination

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to thank you. But this is really excellent. Essentially what's happening here is that you're trusting that the highest date connected to that job will be matched to the second more important join.

Answer (score 5):

Another (not very efficient, but easy to understand) solution for SQL Server 2000:--

```
SELECT  *
FROM    job j
WHERE   j.date = (SELECT MAX(date) 
                  FROM   job 
                  WHERE  id = j.id)
```