# Looking for last date and value from one table and combining with results from another query

Tags: sql

I have a query that is looking at multiple tables A, B, C and is giving me the correct results.

I have a new requirement to slot in the latest set of results from table X.

I have managed to pick up the latest date from table X using a nested inner join but whenever I try to add in another field 'bmi' from table X, I get a message showing 'bmi is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause'. I've tried adding the field 'bmi' into the group function with no success.

My code is here, it would be great if someone could look it over please, I have put in bold the bit where I am trying to add in the field bmi from table 'x'

```
    SELECT
f.name as Home, c.resID, c.surname as Surname, c.forename as Forenames, 
DATEDIFF(DAY, c.DOB, GetDate()) / 365 as Age, 
b.description as Ethnicity,
e.description as Diagnosis, 


case d.diagnosisPrimary when 1 then 'Primary' else '' end as DiagnosisPrimary, d.diagnosisComment,

cast(tm.MaxDate as date) as Last_MUST


FROM cs_clients c




INNER JOIN cs_diagnosis d ON c.guid = d.client
LEFT JOIN cs_facilities f ON c.facility = f.guid
LEFT JOIN cf_enum e ON d.diagnosisType = e.guid and e.type = 'Diagnosis'
LEFT JOIN cf_enum b on c.Ethnicity = b.guid and b.type = 'EthnicOrigin'
```

**inner join (select m.owner, m.bmi, max(mustDate) as MaxDate from cs_mustRecords m group by owner)tm on c.guid = tm.owner**

```
where c.status = 1 and c.leaveDate = '1900-01-01'

ORDER BY f.name, c.surname, c.forename,Diagnosis
```

Comment: sounds like a job for cross apply instead of inner join?

Comment: maybe similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851949/joining-to-max-date-record-in-group

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only ever reference the MAX value of mustDate.  If that's the only value you care about you can try something like this:

```
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT MAX(m.mustDate) as mustDate, m.owner
    FROM cs_mustRecords m
    WHERE m.owner = c.guid
    GROUP BY m.owner
) as tm
```

Or:

```
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 m.mustDate
    FROM cs_mustRecords m
    WHERE m.owner = c.guid
    ORDER BY m.mustDate DESC
) as tm
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the `tm` table query that you're trying to join to. `select m.owner, m.bmi, max(mustDate) as MaxDate from cs_mustRecords m group by owner` is not a valid query. I don't know the column type of `bmi` or how you want the logic to work but you either need to group by that field or use it in an aggregate function.

Here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991079/select-a-column-in-sql-not-in-group-by) with more details on selecting a column not in the group by. Good Luck!